# aria-* attributes are not valid or misspelled

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, lighthouse

I was generally testing Accessibility of a website using Lighthouse in Chrome Audits.

I stumbled upon this warning:

> aria-* attributes are not valid or misspelled.

this is the failing element:

```
<a class="issue-title muted-link" href="#" data-bi-name="issue-expander" aria-role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="issue-26732-body issue-26732-comments issue-26732-reactions issue-26732-reactions-menu" aria-label="Toggle issue">
```

This is the link in case anyone is interested.
[Azure load balancer Feedback Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview#feedback)

To me it seems like the aria-* names and values are valid.

- aria-role = "button" seems to be correct.
- aria-expanded = "false" seems to be correct.
- aria-label seems to be correct
- aria-controls = "..." seems to contain a list of ids, all these ids are present in the DOM ( though i am not sure, if it the accessibility check should fail if they are not present in the DOM and added dynamically )

What can be the reason for this to fail ?

Comment: The link is to Azure Load balancer. Can you please update?

Comment: That is the link to the page I tested.

Comment: updated to point to correct place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct spelling is not `aria-role` but [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#host_general_role). See also the [ARIA Role Attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#aria-role-attribute) in HTML5.2.

[`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded), [`aria-controls`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-controls) and [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) are correct.

I admit that the error message could have been clearer, e.g. by pointing out that `aria-role` is not valid.

Comment: Woah! Face palm.

Comment: Great catch! Easy to miss that one.